# Attempt to issue an MQI call has been made while the connection is started

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am new to IBM MQ. We are using XMS.NET for writing and reading messages from MQ in our .NET windows service. We have been asked to implement transnational session to commit messages after read the message to avoid Unit of Work issue (default to 10,000). We have 1 Writer (send) and 2 Response (Reader) queues. We are using one transnational session /connection for both Write and read messages. Also we are using separate Connection/Session (transnational ) for 2nd response queue (reader). Both readers are using transnational sessions. However, we are seeing Error while Commit after reading messages. (MQCMIT failed reason code 2500 and Comp code 2). If I turn off the one of the reader (through config, not to open connection and session) then we are able to read messages and commit is happening. But we are seeing issues when both readers are open,read messages and Commit from both queues simultaneously. Can someone please guide us if we are missing anything?

Comment: Are you using MQ call back for the reader?  I read that a session that if call back is active you can not use the the same HCONN any other MQ call.  It would probably help people if you post some code that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: Yes, we are using MQ callback for both readers. In the callback method, we are read the message and then issue a commit. Same code for both readers. If I turn-off one of the reader, we are able to read and commit messages though we are using MQCallback.

Comment: What version of MQ are you using?

Comment: Here are the details -
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.5.0.0
Level:       p000-L120604
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Windows
Mode:        32-bit
And we are connecting to MQ using SSL

Comment: I would suggest that you create a simple test case that recreates the problem that you can post in your question so people have something to look at.  I would also note that you are running the GA release of v7.5 what was released July 6th 2012.  There have been 7 fix packs released since that date.  I would suggest that you try the MQ client v7.0.5.7 and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: When you turn off one reader which results in it working, are you turning off the reader that is sharing the transactional session/connection with the writer? I would suggest you have a separate transaction session/connection for each of the writer, the first reader and the second reader and don't share one between the writer and the reader.

Comment: I will try this option.

Comment: Hi Morag Hughson, I have a sharing connection/session between my Writer and one reader only, other reader connection/session doesn't share with any reader or writer.  I have tried my writer is stop connecting and I allowed only two readers to connect. These two readers have separate connections now, but still I am seeing same error. 
If any of the reader is turned-off, then I am not seeing this error and my code works. Both the readers are using message call-back functions.

Comment: I found by adding more debug points, though there are no messages in Reader1's queue, my reader1 is reading messages from Reader2's queue. wondering this is the issue and not allowing Commit?